# Is it possible to modify the origin of a display? (win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I have a number of applications which I cannot modify(no source), they are hard coded to draw at 0,0. Normally this is not a problem however a new project(kiosk) has come along where I need to draw a boarder around the outside of these applications. I am looking for a way to change display range from:

```
X: 0 to 1200
Y: 0 to 900
```

to something like:

```
X: -100 to 1100
Y: -100 to 800
```

I've seen a couple functions on MSDN like SetViewportExtEx, SetWorldTransform which fit the need however if I understand them correctly they don't do a system wide change. They are for the current process only.

I am programming in C++ but if there are settings in the registry/control panel/etc that would also work.

Has anyone else done anything like this before?

Edit 1: Window position is hard coded to 0,0

Comment: Can you not inject a call to one of the mentioned functions using a global hook, or something?

Comment: Do you think the change would be immediate or if there would be timing issues if the application started drawing before I did say a SetWorldTransform call?

Comment: I think only the display driver can do this.  There's a function to get the coordinates of each monitor, but none to set them.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145066.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be overkill, but if it's something you really want to have complete control over, you could always use API hooking to intercept the Window creation by hooking CreateWindow, CreateWindowEx in the target process and altering the X Y coordinates before passing control back to the system.

Popular API hooking libraries include: [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), [Madshi's madCodeHook](http://madshi.net/madCodeHookDescription.htm), and the free, open source [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I am thinking that this is the only way to make this happen. What do you think of ApiHijack? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/apihijack.aspx

Comment: I have not used it, but given that it was last updated over 10 years ago, I would consider a more modern solution.

Answer (score 0):

The route I might take is making a shell application with a window and then setting the parent of the other using "SetParent"

for instance, in C#  I did this...

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo {FileName = "NotePad.exe", WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal};
var runProcess = Process.Start(info);
Thread.Sleep(1000);  // ugly, but more just proving a point
SetParent(runProcess.MainWindowHandle, Handle);
```

and it hosted notepad in my forms window

So, Simply host the window, resize your host to the clients size + a bit,  position the client in your host window where you want, and then draw around the outside.

easy peasy :)

Comment: This seems to be a little weird, causing one of my apps not to start properly (looking into why) also some of the apps who hide themselves (until being told not to) first show( a flicker at best_ in my parent window then pop out to their normal position.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what you mean by 'the applications are hard coded to draw at 0,0'? Does this mean that the position of their windows is set to 0,0, or do they have code to paint at 0,0?

Solution #1
One possible solution would be to use SetWindowPosition to simply move each of the applications to whatever position you desire.

All you would need to do is enumerate the list of HWNDS calling SetWindowPosition on each as necessary.

Solution #2
Set the working area of the desktop to be smaller. This should cause your applications to take up the working area, not the entire screen. You would then be free to put up any additional windows you need, manually position them, and draw your border.

In fact you might consider registering your border windows as 'app bars' which would automatically resize the working area.

Comment: The window position is 0,0. The applications are free to create other windows, which those will also be hard coded to position 0,0. The brute force way I guess is to iterate over all the processes and reset their windows every 100 MS or something. I think there might be flashes or weirdness when these apps open a new window.

Comment: If the applications are opening child windows, you'll definitely get some weird UI effects.

Comment: I like the idea of solution #2, It looks like I can use SystemParametersInfo with the SPI_SETWORKAREA flag. Thanks!

Comment: Damn, didn't work. It still draws at 0,0 I tried : WorkArea.left = 100;
 WorkArea.right = 1580;
 WorkArea.top = 0;
 WorkArea.bottom = 1050;
 SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA, NULL, &WorkArea, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);

Comment: Here's how we are calling it in our code:  
`SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETWORKAREA, 1, lpRcWork, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE|SPIF_SENDCHANGE );` Otherwise I would make sure you are calling this before the other applications have launched. If it still doesn't work, then solution 2 might be a bust.

Comment: I tried the way that you call it and it's weird that Firefox and anything else I am using respects the workarea but when I start up even my own applications which use 0,0 position still go all the way to the left. Thanks again.